# VB.net Literal Data Types: '15D' turns into '15'

Tags: vb.net, types

I'm having a problem, where I'm using a number and letter code  ("15D") in a database field "Shortcut", but when I retrieve it, even though it is treated as a string, VB.NET thinks the "D" stands for decimal and returns "15" instead of a string "15D" stored in database.

```
' assigning from DB
     Me.Filter1.ComboBox.ValueMember = "Shortcut"
     Me.Filter1.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Description"
' using
     Dim myVal as String
     myVal = Me.Filter1.SelectedValue
```

...myVal is then "15", not "15D".

Any idea how to avoid this?

Thanks,

Libor

Comment: Are you sure 15D -- and not 15 -- is actually stored in the database?  What is the datatype of the "shortcut" field?

Comment: VB doesn't care, you have some other issue here.

Comment: @roryap Yes, I'm sure datas are with 'd', only it's a lower case. I can see it even in the description, where I do CONCAT(Shortcut,' ',Description) as Description. I'll better double check the filter settings (though I did already), if it isn't me forcing the integer...

Comment: It was a tiny typing mistake in SQL query hard to find; the query was working even with this mistake, but caused that instead of "Shortcut", "ID" field was fed into ValueMember.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it at the time of read as like this:

```
 Dim myVal as String =  Me.Filter1.SelectedValue
 myVal =New String((From c As Char In myVal Select c Where Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
```

**In a different way you can do the same as :**  [binding combobox from dictonary](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/combovalue.html)

```
    Dim dictonarySource As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    While reader.Read
        Dim shortCut As String = New String((From c As Char In reader.Items("Shortcut") Select c Where Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
        dictonarySource.Add(shortCut, reader.Items("Description"))
    End While
    ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(dictonarySource, Nothing)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be a good suggestion, but a bit of change and considering that I'd have to change it in a code generator and all generated instances, I'll try to find a root cause and resolve it first.